# How can I define a default value in a YAML map?

Tags: java, yaml, jackson2

For a YAML configuration file, I would like to do the following:

**configuration.yml**

```
endpoints:
- name: MyFirstService
  context: my-app
- name: MySecondService
  context:
    default: my-app
    prod: my-app-p
```

I need to configure a special context for one endpoint according to the environment it will be deployed on, but I don't want to have the *default* key if the endpoint only has one context defined.

MyFirstService will always use the "my-app" context, but MySecondService needs to use the "my-app-p" context when deployed on the production environment.

**Is there any way to achieve this in a YAML file ?**

I'm using the Jackson YAML libraries for Java. Also, if something like that is possible, how should my Java Pojo look like ?

*Note:* I'm aware that the following would work. I'd just like to spare the *default* key for endpoints with only one context.

**configuration.yml**

```
endpoints:
- name: MyFirstService
  context:
    default: my-app
- name: MySecondService
  context:
    default: my-app
    prod: my-app-p
```